# unable to chown files or directories from cifs/smb mount

Tags: permissions, chmod, smb, chown, cifs

Looking at several resources I have tried a variety of unsuccessful mount commands to try to be able to chown on a mounted smb/cifs share. My current iteration looks like this

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.0.1/g /mnt/network -o user=user,uid=1001,gid=1001,vers=1.0,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777
```

followed by

```
sudo chown 1001:1001 /mnt/network/storage
```

This produces the following error that I can't seem to get around

```
chown: changing ownership of '/mnt/network/storage': Permission denied
```

I've tried `gid=0,uid=0` and`user=root`

Any insight into what I'm doing wrong or how to make this work would be much appreciated as so far what I've found online doesn't work, Thanks in advance!

I am running on ubuntu 21.04 and some raspberry pi's also running ubuntu (trying to access the same mounted directory which is on an external ssd)